# How to execute Visual Studio Project with MSBuild ? (VB.Net Project)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task

**Aim to Acheive :**
I want to execute my application from msbuild as it shows a lot of helpful information about the execution including the most important the `Time of Execution`.

I have :

> - A Visual Studio Project, and I use Ctrl+F5 to execute my application in Visual Stdio.
> - I want to execute the same Ctrl+F5 execution from the command prompt using MSBuild command.
> - I prefer not to write my own Msbuild execution task for this and want to use the task that Visual Studio uses to do Ctrl+F5.

How do you do it from command prompt using MSBuild ?

I Build my projects with MSBuild as :

```
C:\project> msbuild project.vbproj /t:"Clean;Build"
```

**Now, how to execute it with MSBuild ?**

Comment: Downvoters - which part of this question do you feel needs improvement?  Can you add some comments?  It seems this question isn't 100% clear, but demonstrates what they want to accomplish.

Comment: I have added Aim to achieve to the question, to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use the [`<Exec>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) task... or you could just run the program from the command line explicitly, of course. (I'd only put it in the build file if executing it was naturally part of the build - e.g. an early part of the build created a tool which was then used to preprocess a resource for a later part of the build.)

Comment: Can you give example, how can I use the inbuilt `Exec` task ?

Comment: Reply back.. with an example !

Comment: @Yugal: There's an example in the documentation I linked to.